React: un-invoked useState variables unavailable in event handler in debugger
First ever SO question! Hope I'm doing this right.
Question is, when I am in an event handler's debugger in browser (Chrome), why are useState variables unused by the event handler unavailable?
E.g. in debugger, testBoolean is unavailable. (In "Watch" tab, shows <not available> and in console, shows Uncaught ReferenceError: testBoolean is not defined).
If I comment out the console.log line, the count variable also becomes unavailable.
import { useState } from 'react';
import Game from './Game';

export default function App() {
    const [testBoolean, setTestBoolean] = useState(true);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const handleClick = () => {
        setCount(c => c + 1);
        console.log(count);
        debugger
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Clicked {count} times</button>
        </div>
    )
}

Have tried searching e.g. react debugger unused useState variables not available in event handler but most threads I find deal with event handlers having stale useState values which is an entirely different topic. Some thoughts:

handleClick is an arrow function, so I believe it should close over other consts in the function component?
when handleClick is invoked, the component function has run and returned the virtual DOM elements, so the useState variables should have already been declared.

Looking forward to any insights, seems crucial to understanding event flow / React and would love to understand going forward. Thank you.

Modern web browsers do many optimizations to improve performance. One of them is that they can determine whether a variable will be needed by a closure. If so, the variable must be allocated on the heap (so that it will still exist when your closure executes). If not, it can be allocated on the stack. Since you're not using the variable in a closure, the browser has decided to put it on the stack. As a result, as soon as App finishes running, that variable is released.
For normal code execution this will have no impact at all, since it's only done if it will have no impact. But if you pause the code (with debugger or a breakpoint) you can notice that the variable has been optimized away.

TYSM!! I'm new and can't upvote stuff yet, so wanted to give thanks directly. I would've been fine if there was a flaw in my understanding of e.g. closures so I can patch that flaw, but relieved to know it wasn't that and instead gained insight into browser behavior. Ty! :)
